# Kafka Stream to divide job & joining them

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have requirement where I get record into topic. With single record I create n different jobs(which should get distributed). Once I successfully process n jobs I need push successfully processed record. Does it qualify for Kafka streams? Basically what I am looking at is , I have video (lets say 20min duration) which needs to be transcoded. I will create 4 tasks(each 5 min) , each worker will process these 4 tasks individually. Once all 4 tasks are completed I need to stitch it back together. I am trying to see if KafaStreams is possible fit to distribute the jobs & then join.

Answer (score 0):

I probably wouldn't recommend using kafka streams for the data itself as it is not meant to deal with such large messages like videos are. But you can use it as a messaging system, saying:

1. First event comes, hey I got a new video to process
2. You trigger the software from within your stream
3. After completion, the software writes another event into a kafka topic to say, it has finished it's job
4. The kafka streams application could then process this event to trigger the other software to do it's job

Hope it helps.